# What does gmail response "Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (in reply to MAIL FROM command))" means?

Tags: email, email-bounces

When out of office mails from our company go to a gmail address, we get this error in return:

> May  2 12:59:29 lg-info-mail postfix/smtp[22620]: AB34490FD1:
>   to=,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=0.11,
>   delays=0.01/0/0.1/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26] said: 550 Requested action
>   not taken: mailbox unavailable (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

My mail has X-Envelope-From and From set.

What does "in reply to MAIL FROM command" means exactly? What is my mail lacking of?

Comment: Does your autoresponder use a fake email address?

Comment: First I do not know how to do this. I nearly sure it doesn't. The respons is Exchange 2010 Out of office TNEF mail which is sent with an empty sender. I should have talked about this. But, who is issuing the MAIL FROM command and what is empty?

Comment: In this context, the mail server which contacted Google issued the MAIL FROM command. The bounce message should have included the headers of the rejected message. It would be a good idea to look at that.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know how to do this. There is some kind of mail id (AB34490FD1) but I can't postcat -vq it. It says "no such file or directory". I don't know if this error is a mail and in which mailbox it was sent. Postfix is MTA between my Exchange 2010 and the rest of the world by the way.

Comment: When I try to send a mail to gmail (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com) manually, and I enter en empty mail from (MAIL FROM:<>), I get the error "550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable". So, this is, I believe, exactly when I get my error.

Comment: OK, well, that's a problem on Google's end. You can't really fix that.

Comment: I can. I believe the problem I'm facing (https://serverfault.com/questions/963811/add-sender-to-my-exchange-out-of-office-mails-which-are-sent-via-postfix-with-an) is that Postfix removes the Return-Path from my email because if I bypass my postfix the out of office is sent and received by Google.

Comment: 2 comments earlier, I said "So, this is, I believe, exactly when I get my error." when my server tries to do a MAIL FROM:<> to Google. But now I'm thinking that it might be Google that is doing a MAIL FROM:<> to my server to find out if the sender (of the out of office mail, wich is <>) is correct. And my server might say "mailbox unavailable". Do you think it's possible? As https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification says.

Comment: If you suspect Postfix is stripping off the sender address, then you need to be looking at its logs.